# Retrieving list of variables names used in a C# file

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there is a way i can write a method which returns all the variable names used in the C# file. Is it even possible? Any one ever done anything like this? i want a list of variable names.

Comment: Do you want to do this from a .cs file, or from a compiled exe/dll?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is.

You have to use [Roslyn](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27746) to parse the `C#` code file into syntax tree, and after retrive the variables you need after semantic analysis.

Here can find more examples on how can do that:

[Getting Started: Semantic Analysis - C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh543918.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this from a compiled DLL or EXE, then no, this is not possible.

While you can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve the member names of types, as well as fields or properties of the types, the local variable names are not compiled into the IL.  There is no way to retrieve them, as they no longer exist.

Doing this from a .CS file can be done via Rosyln, as [explained by Tigran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12182016/65358).

Comment: Is this the case even if you have the PDB?